# GSuite services - Calendar - bug with timezone and years?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, timezone, google-calendar-api

I'm playing with the GSuite services Calendar (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar) to retrieve events from my Google Calendar.

I'm french (this is important for timezone).

I noticed something strange :

- On my Google Calendar, I create an event, for exemple: 2017-11-17 from 10am to 18pm (notice the year 2017).
- With Javascript and calendar service API, I retrieve this event and print start and end date:

```js
function runMe() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  Logger.log('My default calendar is set to the time zone "%s".', calendar.getTimeZone());

  const events = calendar.getEvents(new Date(2017, 10, 17), new Date(2017, 10, 18));
  events.forEach(event => Logger.log (event.getStartTime()+" - "+event.getEndTime()));
}
// logs: 
// My default calendar is set to the time zone "Europe/Paris".
// Fri Nov 17 2017 09:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) - Fri Nov 17 2017 17:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)
```

The date is not correct, I expect `Fri Nov 17 2017 10:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) - Fri Nov 17 2017 18:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)`

- Now, on my Google Calendar, I create another event at the same date, but on year 2018.
- With Javascript and calendar service API, I retrieve this event and print start and end date:

```js
...
function runMe() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  Logger.log('My default calendar is set to the time zone "%s".', calendar.getTimeZone());

  const events = calendar.getEvents(new Date(2018, 10, 17), new Date(2018, 10, 18));
  events.forEach(event => Logger.log (event.getStartTime()+" - "+event.getEndTime()));
}
// logs:
// My default calendar is set to the time zone "Europe/Paris".
// Sat Nov 17 2018 10:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale) - Sat Nov 17 2018 18:00:00 GMT+0100 (heure normale d’Europe centrale)
```

The date is correct.

What happened?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve].

Comment: What is your calendar time zone? You can view this from [https://calendar.google.com](https://calendar.google.com), clicking the `⋮` to the right of the calendar name on the left-side bar and pressing `Settings`.

Comment: `(GMT+02:00) Heure d’Europe centrale - Paris`

Comment: @Cooper: I just edited the code sample

Comment: What's the script timezone?

Comment: `"timeZone": "Europe/Paris"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This appears to be a bug!

I've done a lot of testing regarding this and it appears that the Calendar API returns the time incorrectly between the period between when DST ended in 2017, and when it began again in 2018.

I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker for you, detailing the behaviour:

- [Calendar API returns incorrect event start and end time for events between end of DST 2017 and beginning of DST 2018](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156891661)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.